# Protein-rich vegetarian recipes without nuts

Tags: protein, vegetarian-diet

I just recently made the transition to becoming vegetarian. I'm loving it so far and feel great, but could use some new recipes.

I personally do not like nuts so finding ways to get protein in my diet has been a little bit of a struggle so far. If anyone has any ideas for good protein rich foods I'd love to try them out!

Comment: This question is too broadly scoped in my opinion. Most people are surprised to learn that grains and most vegetables provide significant quantities of protein. Hey, even chocolate has protein. The list of answers could go on forever. But unless your diet is extremely restricted, chances are good that you're getting enough protein. Can you narrow this question down to ask something more specific? Also, have you seen  [this question on vegetarian protein sources?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-are-the-highest-protein-sources-for-vegetarians-vegans)

Comment: Welcome to Vegetarianism Stack Echange site. As said by Zanna (and comment up-voters), your question is too broad. Please, take a look at the link in her post and/or narrow the topic of your question. Also, the [ask] help page can be helpful to you.

Comment: Hemp seeds are a complete protein worth looking into. Wheat germs, beer yeast, phytoplankton — also excellent protein sources.

Answer (score 2):

[**Quinoa**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinoa) (pronounced *keenwa*). It is one of the few vegan foods with a complete amino acid profile.

Quinoa is also yummy. I eat it as a hot cereal, with my smoothies, and as a side dish.

As far as vegan recipes go, this can vary greatly among individual own tastes, but for myself I have found that keeping it simple is profound, grow my own tomatoes, eat tropical fruits that are so ripe they have mold on them, but don't eat the mold, except Mangoes: wait till they are on the ground in the morning, the ones with a small crack are best. My entire grocery shopping list for food is quinoa, papayas, acacia berries, beets which baked are not only the edible version of canned and taste good. Keep the roots of the beets, for nitrate smoothies, or toss if you don't need high nitrate smoothies, and the leaves are awesome salads, passion fruit, dragon fruit, Bok Choi, sweet peepers, fresh raw sweet peas, bananas, Fuji water, blueberries, ginger roots, avocados, red onions, red potatoes, olive oil, pasta, garlic, almond and coconut milk, yeast, whole grain flour, A vegan protein shake mix. Oh and Himalayan pink sea salt.

Also I quit laughing at people who ate things like pink salt, and began learning why they ate things like pink salt. Eat to live not live to eat.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that rice and lentils are an important protein staple in vegetarian societies of the world. Rice and legumes are very standard in the daily diets of most Indians, especially where meat eating is prohibited.

> "The lentils in dal provide complementary proteins and some essential amino acids,” says Majmudar. “Grains like wheat (in chapati) or rice provide the other half of the nutritional combination. This forms a dish that is a complete protein source.”

Quoted in [this menshealth.com article](http://www.menshealth.com.sg/weight-loss-nutrition/dal-your-protein-perfect-dish/).

The beautiful thing about dahl or lentils is that you can make a variety of foods, like soups. You can make patties like vegetarian burgers, or you can even purchase lentil flour and make make very delicious steamed cakes called "Dokla".

You can also try making salads or pastas using tahini (a rich creamy paste made from sesame seeds) which many vegans use a cheese sauce substitute. It is high in protein.